# How to insert data in sqlite django (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asdf')

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error:

> (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'any thing'

I am absolutely new in Django and Python, I want to insert data in table through Django's ORM, but I can't and I tried very much to solve it but different errors comes at different stages, please help me with little explanation:

Here is my *views.py*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, request, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from .models import Signup
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import sqlite3


def first_page(request):
    username = request.GET['txtname']
    password = request.GET['txtpassword']
    contact = request.GET['txtcontact']
    address = request.GET['txtaddress']

    # db = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase')
    # cursor = db.cursor()
    # cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Signup(name, password, contact, address) VALUES (?,?,?,?)''', (username, password, contact, address))
    signup = Signup(username, password, contact, address)
    signup.save()
    return render_to_response("first_page.html", {'name': username,
                                                  'password': password,
                                                  'contact': contact,
                                                  'address': address})


def sign_up(request):
    return render_to_response("signup.html")
```

here is my models.py

```
 from django.db import models


class Signup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

here is my sigup.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="." method="get">

        <label for="txtname">Name</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="txtname" name="txtname"/><br/><br/><br/>

        <label for="txtpassword">Password</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="password" id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword"/><br/><br/><br/>

        <label for="txtcontact">Contact</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="number" id="txtcontact" name="txtcontact"/><br/><br/><br/>

        <label for="txtaddress">Address</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="txtaddress" name="txtaddress"/><br/><br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" id="btnsignup" name="btnsignup" value="Register">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from reg.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^first/', first_page),
    url(r'^register$', sign_up),
    url(r'^$', first_page),
]
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the error.

Comment: Also, what actions and values led to the error? It's very hard to work with just an error message and lots of code.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on error you had mentioned here `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'any thing'`:** As you defined contact as `IntegerField()` and then you passed its `value` as **any thing** inside your contact textbox field. Try integer like 123.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, two main issues here -->

1.`contact = models.IntegerField()` This should ideally not be stored as integer, as the contact number has nothing to do with Integer properties. Try using CharField.

2.If you want it to be Integer, do a simple -->

```
contact = request.GET['txtcontact']
contactInt = int(request.GET['txtcontact'])
signup = Signup(username, password, contactInt, address)
```

Although point 2 is not the way to do it. If the contact number is large, it may not even get supported by int. Also, something like +21 232675 67612 has a plus sign, and cannot be stored as an int.